# Windows 10 Explorer search cant find files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

While recently trying to located some lost files, I noticed that my Windows Explorer search was not functioning properly. As a test, I typed in a file I knew existed in a location:

C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Adobe\Premiere Pro\11.0\Profile\Layouts\WorkspaceConfig.xml

so I typed this in the search field in Windows Explorer (searching the entire C drive), and the search results came back empty.

I ran a second test on C drive for another random file and the same thing happened. No results. I also tried logging into another account on Windows (barebone), with the same issues present.

Can anyone explain this, and what I might do to go about fixing it?

Running Windows 10 Pro 21H1 OS build 19043.1586

Comment: Not an answer, but I personally have often found Windows Search to be unreliable, especially if Windows hasn't [indexed the file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/search-indexing-in-windows-10-faq-da061c83-af6b-095c-0f7a-4dfecda4d15a) for some reason. Using a third-party program to search your disk may yield more reliable results.

Comment: Two alternatives I've used: DocFetcher, which builds indices, and Agent Ransack, for "live" searches.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered kind of the same issue: I have added the whole Music folder to search faster inside. One day I tried to search here files with extension .mp3, it returned nothing! I went in the indexing settings and removed this folder from indexing. I let the files database being rebuilt and searched "mp3" again: voilà my files are back!
Maybe the search is slower now, but at least it works.
Hope it helped someone here ;)